# Варианты заполнения поля и идея реализации этой системы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте.

Постараюсь объяснить ситуацию на пальцах: есть страница, на которой можно посмотреть список всех заказов (и провести поиск среди них). У каждого заказа имеется несколько характеристик, в том числе и идентификтора заказчика.

Для облегчения поиска по заказчикам, под полем ввода имени появляется **ниспадающий список со всеми заказчиками**. Чтобы сделать систему максимально быстрой, список отдается пользователю при загрузке страницы в виде JS объекта. Далее (при вводе данных) осуществляется перебор всех юзеров и формирование таблицы.

Проблема в том, что таблица, из которой берется список, довольно большая (**8-10 тыс. записей**) и загрузка ее на страницу идет с зависанием (как и поиск в ней).

Сам вопрос: **как лучше организовать эту систему? (код не нужен, нужна лишь идея/структура и т.д. для быстрого и эффективного поиска)**

Пример системы (это не оригинальный код, а лишь копия некоторых функций и обработчиков событий):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*
         Получение списка, для упрощения сделал готовый объект
         для примера
    */
  lastElement = null;
  userList = [{
    ID: 1,
    Name: 'Иванов Иван Иванович',
    Phone: 123
  }, {
    ID: 2,
    Name: 'Петров Петр Петрович',
    Phone: 1243
  }, {
    ID: 3,
    Name: 'Максимов Максим Максимович',
    Phone: 1253
  }, {
    ID: 4,
    Name: 'Петров Иван Иванович',
    Phone: 1723
  }, {
    ID: 5,
    Name: 'Иванов Петр Иванович',
    Phone: 1236
  }, {
    ID: 6,
    Name: 'Иванов Иван Петрович',
    Phone: 1253
  }, {
    ID: 7,
    Name: 'Максимов Иван Иванович',
    Phone: 1323
  }, {
    ID: 8,
    Name: 'Иванов Максим Иванович',
    Phone: 1213
  }, {
    ID: 9,
    Name: 'Иванов Иван Максимович',
    Phone: 123
  }, {
    ID: 10,
    Name: 'Даниилов Данил Данилович',
    Phone: 1623
  }, {
    ID: 11,
    Name: 'Примеров Пример Примерович',
    Phone: 123
  }, {
    ID: 12,
    Name: 'Антонов Антон Антонович',
    Phone: 14223
  }, {
    ID: 13,
    Name: 'Кириллов Кирилл Кириллович',
    Phone: 12123
  }, {
    ID: 14,
    Name: 'Иоанов Иоан Иоанович',
    Phone: 12123
  }, {
    ID: 15,
    Name: 'Николаев Николай Николаевич',
    Phone: 123
  }, {
    ID: 16,
    Name: 'Анатольев Анатолий Анатольевич',
    Phone: 12683
  }, {
    ID: 17,
    Name: 'Анатольев Иван Иванович',
    Phone: 122343
  }, {
    ID: 18,
    Name: 'Иванов Анатолий Иванович',
    Phone: 123
  }, {
    ID: 19,
    Name: 'Иванов Иван Анатольевич',
    Phone: 122453
  }, {
    ID: 20,
    Name: 'Иоанов Иван Иванович',
    Phone: 12363
  }, {
    ID: 21,
    Name: 'Иванов Иоан Максимович',
    Phone: 120533
  }, {
    ID: 22,
    Name: 'Максимов Иван Максимович',
    Phone: 12123
  }, {
    ID: 23,
    Name: 'Примеров Иван Максимович',
    Phone: 12633
  }];
  $("body").append("<div id='searchPanel'><table id='searchTable' class='parametres hightlightTR'></table></div>");
  var controlElement = $("#searchPanel");
  var table = $("#searchTable");

  function OnSearch(l) {
    var search = $(l).val();
    var idx = 0;
    var j = userList.length;
    var len = j;
    var i = 0;
    var dataHTML = "";
    var toSetString = "";
    while (--j) {
      i = len - j;
      elem = userList[i];
      toSetString = elem.Name.concat(" (", elem.Phone, ")");

      if (search.length > 0) {
        idx = elem.Name.indexOf(search);
        if (idx !== -1) {
          dataHTML = dataHTML.concat("<tr k='", i, "'><td>",
            toSetString.substr(0, idx).concat("<b>", search, "</b>", toSetString.substr(idx + search.length)));
        }
      } else dataHTML = dataHTML.concat("<tr k='", i, "'><td>", toSetString, "</td></tr>");
    }
    table.html(dataHTML);
  }

  function ShowHelp(l) {
    lastElement = $(l);
    var pos = $(l).offset(),
      h = $(l).height(),
      topPos = pos.top + h + 5;

    h = 300;
    controlElement.css({
      top: topPos,
      left: pos.left,
      height: h
    });
    controlElement.fadeIn(100);

    table.empty().append("<caption>Загрузка списка... Пожалуйста, подождите</caption>");
    OnSearch(l);
  }

  function HideHelp() {
    $("#searchPanel").fadeOut(100);
  }

  function OnSelect(l) {
    var value = userList[parseInt($(l).attr("k"))].Name;
    lastElement.val(value);
  }



  $("input[name=myinput]").on("click", function(e) {
    ShowHelp(e.currentTarget);
  });
  $("input[name=myinput]").on("input", function(e) {
    ShowHelp(e.currentTarget);
  });
  $("input[name=myinput]").on("blur", function(e) {
    HideHelp();
  });
  $("#searchTable").on("mousedown", "tr", function(e) {
    OnSelect(e.currentTarget)
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}
#searchPanel {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
  text-align: left
}
.hightlightTR {
  width: 100%;
}
.hightlightTR tr:hover {
  background-color: #479EC4;
  border: 1px blue outset;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.parametres td,
.parametres th {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='myinput'>
```

---

**Sasha Omelchenko**

> Общая схема примерно такая: ввод нескольких букв в поле → отправка данных на сервер аяксом→ поиск введенных данных на сервере по таблице → возврат данных на страницу.

Так работала первая версия этой системы. На событие INPUT вешался обработчик, который каждый раз отправлял данные на сервер. Но из-за ввода данных в поле "залпом" сервер был завален большим количеством запросов. Потом была добавлена задержка на ожидание ввода (в 400 мс) перед отправкой данных. Так как таблица довольно большая, на формирование ответа уходит порядка 1-2 секунд (если под условие поиска подходит 1+ тыс. строк), что, согласитесь, довольно неприятно. Именно после этого было решено хранить заранее сформированный список в базе данных и обновлять его только при регистрации пользователей или обновлении их данных.

Comment: Думаю, что имеет смысл формировать этот список не сразу при загрузке системы. После того как пользователь ввел значение (фильтр), делать запрос на сервер (опции: начинается с, находится в)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлять на страницу такое количество данных и осуществлять по ним поиск при помощи js это действительно плохая идея с низкой производительностью. Выводите на страницу только результаты поиска. Общая схема примерно такая: ввод нескольких букв в поле → отправка данных на сервер аяксом→ поиск введенных данных на сервере по таблице → возврат данных на страницу.

Comment: Я подробнее описал работу всей системы в вопросе. Если невозможно создать сейчас (при текущей системе на стороне сервера) оптимального решения на стороне клиента, то каким образом можно изменить все систему для достижения лучшего результата?

Comment: вы написали, что ответом на аякс-запрос может быть 1 тыс и более строк, но может и не надо отдавать весь список, а только где есть совпадения по первым буквам фамилии (при вводе "иван" вряд ли вы ищете "Максимов Григорий ИВАНович")? дополнительно ускорить поиск может разбиение всего поля "заказчик" на "фамилия заказчика", "имя заказчика", "отчество заказчика". в таком случае строка, по которой ведется поиск, будет короче, а значит и поиск по ней быстрее.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, это будет самым оптимальным решением. Спасибо